# flutter web app iframe keyboard extra space on top in android chrome

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, iframe

I am render a iframe inside a flutter web app. whenever there is keyboard opened extra scrollable space is getting generated

sample code to create iframe in flutter web app

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;

class IframeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const IframeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<IframeView> createState() => _IframeViewState();
}

class _IframeViewState extends State<IframeView> {
  late String _idValue;

  late Key iframeKey;

  Future<String> _initializeIframe(BuildContext context) async {
    _idValue = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    var iframeView = html.IFrameElement();
    iframeView.attributes = {
      'src': 'https://bing.com',
      'name': _idValue,
    };
    iframeView.style.setProperty('object-fit', 'cover');
    iframeView.style.setProperty('border', 'none');
    iframeView.style.setProperty('height', '100%');
    iframeView.style.setProperty('width', '100%');

    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      _idValue,
      (viewId) => iframeView,
    );

    iframeKey = Key(_idValue);

    return _idValue;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeIframe(context);
  }

  final ValueNotifier<double?> actualWidth = ValueNotifier(null);

  Widget onBuild(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: HtmlElementView(
        viewType: _idValue,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return onBuild(context);
  }
}
```

[when inspected over chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu8s5.jpg)

[screenshot in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coiRo.jpg)

there should not be extra whitespace when keyboard is triggered from the iframe of flutter web-app. Tried in other browser like firefox focus but there no issue. But when tested with chrome inspect that extra space is part of flutter view that was created.